# How to use scanner "The console won't open with my piece of code"

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to use a scanner but the pieces of code that I have don't work. I am trying to create a pop up in the console where I can write but it does not work.

I have tried to create two different variables for the scanner but it does not work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Functions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String hello = "Hello";
    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);

       }

}
```

I expect to be able to use user input but the console doesn't have anything showing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Scanner class, you can use for example the method next() or nextDouble(). Before you can print an information message like this:

```java
System.out.println("Input: ");
String s = name.next();
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you need to call a method from the `Scanner`. If it isn't clear why, your code just makes a `String` and a `Scanner` object. The `Scanner` class has many methods, like `next()`, `nextLine()`, `nextInt()` etc. that return the user input for that `Scanner` object.
Use the following code:

```
String hello = name.nextLine();
```

This will assign `hello` with the input of `name`.
One thing to note, is that if the variable type inputted isn't the same as the type of the method, for example, the input is a `double` type but you invoked `nextInt()`, it will throw `java.util.InputMismatchException`.